# Apply a function that iterate over a group in data.table r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a sample data.table as below

```
dt = data.table(a= c("A","A","A","A","B","B"), b= c   
("D","D","D","D","E","E"), c= c("My name is ABC","I am going to  
school","name is Bond","My school is XYZ","My name is ABC set 2","My name  
is ABC set 1") )
```

Now I need to find the cosine similarity between every row and the other row of column "c", within a group, grouped by Column "a" and Column "b" and place the text with the maximum cosine value in a new column "d", something like below.

```
dt2 = data.table(a= c("A","A","A","A","B","B"), b= 
c("D","D","D","D","E","E"), c= c("My name is ABC",
"I am going to school","name is Bond","My school is XYZ",
"My name is ABC  set 2","My  name is ABC set 1"), 
d= c("name is Bond" ,"I am going to school","My name is ABC",
"My school is XYZ","My name is ABC set 1","My name is ABC set 2"))
```

Below is the cosine function, that returns the value similarity between two character vectors. Have commented out the code, since it creates temporary files

```
#library(lsa)
#cosine = function(x,y){
#td = tempfile()
#dir.create(td)
#f1 <- unlist(strsplit( as.character(x), split = " "))  
#f1 = f1[grepl("[[:alnum:]]",f1 )]
#f2 <- unlist(strsplit( as.character(y), split = " "))  
#f2 = f2[grepl("[[:alnum:]]",f2 )]
#write( c(f1), file=paste(td, "D1", sep="/"))
#write( c(f2), file=paste(td, "D2", sep="/"))
#myMatrix = textmatrix(td, minWordLength=1)
#unlink(td, recursive=TRUE)
#res <- lsa::cosine(myMatrix[,1], myMatrix[,2])
#return(res)
#}
```

I think it should be somewhat like this, but do not have an idea to implement it

```
testm[, lapply(.SD,MATCH:= cosine(x,y)),
by= .(ColumnA,ColumnB), .SDcols      =   c  ("DESCRIPTION")]
```

Comment: You should write complete code with appropriate library() calls (showing for example, where `textmatrix` came from). Also, please don't give sample code that messes with files on users' computers unless that's part of the core issue.

Comment: @Frank , lets assume the function returns the cosine similarity of two texts passed.